# Send string to php server and use it

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

Im trying to send a string to a php server, but for some reason, Im not able to read the string on the server... I tried many ways to type it well but it seems like I never got the correct syntax. Anyone have clues?

```
var command="";
if(document.getElementById("Text_1").value != "" && document.getElementById("Text_2").value != "")
        {
            command += " " + document.getElementById("Text_1").value + " " + document.getElementById("Text_2").value;
        }       

        alert(command);

        xmlhttp.open("POST", "server.php", false);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('info', command)
                     //TRIED xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("info, command")
                     //TRIED xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('info', 'command')
                     //TRIED many others sketchy things...
        xmlhttp.send();
        //TRIED xmlhttp.send(command);
        var output = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

On php server :

```
<?php

$parameter = $_POST['command']; 

$output = exec("someexecutable.exe $parameter");

echo json_encode($parameter);
?>
```

For them wondering, if I hardcode $parameter with a right string, it works, so the executable isn't the problem. The server just cant get the value of the string in $_POST.

Comment: What's the value of command before it's sent? Then what is the the value of the $_POST array?

Comment: You *might* wanna use [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) on your `$parameter`.  I can do some pretty nasty things (worse than just SQL injection) if I can run arbitrary commands on your server!

Comment: So far the value of command is the concatenation of text_1 and text_2, so indeed I confirmed that the string I send is good. For $_POST, I don't know, since its server side I got no idea how to check it because I cant use things like alertbox to popup the content. I tried to simply catch it on the server and throw it back to read it on javascript client side, but it doesn't work. It throw me back junks. But I got this error : Undefined error index : command.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat How exactly you use it and how does it protect me exactly? (I began js/css/php 1 week and half ago...)

Comment: @MacGruber: `escapeshellarg($_POST['command'])`.  It protects the string so it's treated as one parameter.  What would happen if I sent your server a command of: `exit && del file` or something similar?  Your server would run `someexecutable.exe exit && del file`. `escapeshellarg` would make that `someexecutable.exe 'exit && del file'`.  (EDIT: I'm a Linux guy, had to update the command for Windows.)

Comment: Thank you! Will sleep less stupid tonight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setRequestHeader` is used to set headers on the request.  Things like `Content-type` and `Content-length`.

You need to pass the data to `send()`.  For `$_POST` to work, they need to be in `key=val&vey2=val2` format.  Actually, in newer browsers, you can use `FormData`.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "server.php", false);

// To emulate a `<form>` POST
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

// To get the response, you need to set a callback
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    // readyState 4 = complete
    // status = 200 OK
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        var output = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
};

// Create the Form Data
var params = new FormData;
params.append('command', command);

xmlhttp.send(params);
```

P.S. You should run [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) before running your command.  This could be worse than just SQL injection if people can run arbitrary commands on your server.

```
<?php
$parameter = escapeshellarg($_POST['command']);
$output = exec("someexecutable.exe $parameter");
?>
```

P.P.S. `escapeshellarg()` will make your command treat the *entire* `$_POST['command']` string as *one* parameter.  If you don't want that, then you'll need to POST an *array* from your JavaScript.

```
// Create the Form Data
var params = new FormData;
params.append('command[]', document.getElementById("Text_1").value);
params.append('command[]', document.getElementById("Text_2").value);

xmlhttp.send(params);
```

Now `$_POST['command']` will be an array, so you'll have to run the command like so:

```
<?php
$parameters = array_map('escapeshellarg', $_POST['command']);
$output = exec("someexecutable.exe ".implode(' ', $parameters));
?>
```

Comment: Jesus Christ it works, you got all my thanks @Rocket Hazmat!